# Extract each match+context of +/-N rows even if contiguous/overlapping (grep/sed/awk/powershell/etc)

Tags: powershell, sed, command-line, grep, matching

I encountered an unexpected problem when using grep -B 10 -A 10 to get keywords + context rows. If there was a match within that context, then it did not count that as a separate match, but extended the context. This problem has been encountered before: [Do not merge the context of contiguous matches with grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163717/do-not-merge-the-context-of-contiguous-matches-with-grep)

Thus, when finding matches from:

```
a
b
match1
c
d
e
match2
f
match3
g
h
i
j
```

I'd like to get (with whatever delimiter). Here the example is with N=2 in either direction, but I would like a general solution where the number is easy to tweak.

```
b
match1
c
d
--
d
e
match2
f
match3
--
match2
f
match3
g
h
--
```

There is a small python script written as answer, but given it's now 9 years later, maybe there is a better way. I'm working with huge files (100M+ rows), so the python script does not really do the job as well.

Maybe there is some new or old commandline tool that does this?

Comment: 10 lines would be great ;)

Comment: I'd suggest to change your sample in the question to reflect this and doing so will give an easy way to test for those who wish to answer.. there's also the question whether you can have multiple overlaps in those 10 lines or is the overlap restricted to maximum one match

Comment: Ah, thanks, in this case I'd like a general solution indeed. I edited the text. Multiple overlaps are possible. Would simply like the context of each match, irrespective of whats in it - could be other matches in there too. But the other matches do not extend the context of another match.

Comment: I tried a solution with `perl`, there's no simple solution because of multiple overlapping cases.. the python solution in linked question saves entire file in array, which won't help with large files.. thus the complexity.. speed is going to be issue unless you write it in `C/Rust/etc`

Answer (score 1):

Since PowerShell is tagged here, you can do the following which should be easy on memory at the expense of speed. We could potentially read the file in other ways that are more efficient, but you lose some conciseness.

```
$StringMatch = 'match' # Text you want to match
$n = 2 # Context number or the number of lines above and below the match
$sectionEnd = $false
$tracker = [collections.queue]::new()
# You may want to feed in multiple files, which can be done with a surrounding foreach loop at this spot
get-content a.txt -readcount 1 | foreach-object -Process {
    $sectionEnd = $false
    $tracker.Enqueue($_)
    if ($tracker.count -gt ($n*2+1)) {
        $null = $tracker.Dequeue()
    }
    if ($tracker.count -eq ($n*2+1) -and $tracker.ToArray()[$n] -match $StringMatch) {
        $tracker
        "----------"
        $sectionEnd = $true
    }
} -End { # -End block can be removed if you don't want to output a final misaligned $tracker
    if (!$sectionEnd -and $tracker.ToArray() -match $StringMatch) {
        $tracker
        "---------"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `perl` script named `context.pl` where `$n` controls the number of context lines.

```perl
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = ""; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    sub BEGIN {
        $n = 3;
    }
    {
        $j = $. % $n;
        if (/match/) {
            for ($i = $j; $i < $j + $n; ++$i) {
                print $buf{$i % $n};
            }
            print $_;
            $fp = tell ARGV;
            foreach $_ (1 .. $n) {
                unless (eof) {
                    $line = <ARGV>;
                    print $line;
                }
            }
            print "--\n";
            seek ARGV, $fp, 0;
        }
        $buf{$j} = $_;
    }
}
```

The script works by having a buffer of size `$n` which saves the previous `$n` lines. Whenever there is a match, the buffer content is printed, followed by current line. Then, `$fp` saves the current file location. Then, next `$n` lines are fetched to be printed, followed by the delimiter `--`. The file location is then restored to start processing from the next line to current matching line.

Here's a sample run with `$n = 2`:

```
$ perl context.pl ip.txt
a
b
match1
c
d
--
d
e
match2
f
match3
--
match2
f
match3
g
h
--
```

There are corner case issues. If the file doesn't end with `$n` lines after the last match, the results are mangled. For example, with the changed input as shown below and `$n = 4`:

```
$ cat ip.txt
a
b
match1
match2
c
$ perl context.pl ip.txt
a
b
match1
match2
c
--
b
match1
a
match2
c
--
```